# Is there a way to share Firebase Auth sign in between iOS and WatchOS apps?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, watchos

I'm working on an app where I'm using anonymous sign in from the iOS app and I would like to share that authentication with the WatchOS app. I've set the keychain access group to be the same on both the ios and watchos apps and call `Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup` but the watchOS app returns nil for the user.

I came across some [old forum posts](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/5938) saying that keychain access sharing between iOS and Watch is no longer possible from WatchOS 2 but I wasn't sure if that was still the case.

Am I just doing something wrong or do I need to do something else to share authentication between the two?

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081068/sending-firebase-reference-to-apple-watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned that it doesn't work in the simulator but it does work on an actual device.

Comment: How did you manage to do that? I have been trying with no luck, even on physical devices the key chains are not being shared.

Comment: Something that's not in the sample that has worked for me is to set auth.shareAuthStateAcrossDevices to true on the auth object prior to the auth.useUserAccessGroup call

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix this issue by calling on both devices (iPhone and Apple Watch):

```swift
Auth.auth().shareAuthStateAcrossDevices = true
```

I added it before my call to `useUserAccessGroup`.

For the group ID I had to use `com.mycompany.AppGroup` as opposed to `XXXXXX.com.mycompany.AppGroup`

The Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/single-sign-on) on the topic is quite misleading.

*(This was for [Whisper Memos](https://whispermemos.com/) - building Apple Watch App)*